# Include Assessment Points in FHIR Task for Grouping Questionnaires?

Tags: hl7-fhir

we are using FHIR v4 and the Task resource to send Questionnaires to the users. Now, we want to improve the grouping and sorting of these tasks by including assessment points. These assessment points could be, for example, T0 for the time of arrival, T1 for a 2-week follow-up, and so on.

**Inclusion in FHIR Task**: Is there a recommended way to include these assessment points directly into the FHIR Task resource? We are looking for a standardized way to include this metadata so it's easily queryable (if possible).

**Storing Assessment Points**: We also need to store a list of available assessment points that users can choose from when creating new tasks. Is there a specific FHIR resource or best practice for storing this kind of reference data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the timing at which Questionnaires are to be solicited is established by a protocol (PlanDefinition) with ActivityDefinitions for each.  That's where timing points would typically live.  However, you could capture the timing code on each Task using the https://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/fhir-extensions/StructureDefinition-relative-date.html extension - use the 'code' element.

Comment: Thank you for the extension and we we'll look into the other resources 